# How to change css value of an element with Locomotive Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, locomotive-scroll

I'm looking for a soultion when a section is out of viewport, Locomotive scroll will change the css attributes on another element and when is in viewport, it reverts that back.

I couldn't find a soulution or a topic. basic knowledge of JS. So, appreaciate if someone can help me out to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

This function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279138/3807365 is pretty simple to incorporate on scroll.

```
function isInView(el) {
  const box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return box.top < window.innerHeight && box.bottom >= 0;
}
```

Lets try

```js
function isInView(el) {
  const box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return box.top < window.innerHeight && box.bottom >= 0;
}

var div1 = document.querySelector(".div1")
var div2 = document.querySelector(".div2")

window.onscroll = function() {

  if (isInView(div1)) {
    div2.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    div2.classList.remove("active");
  }

  if (isInView(div2)) {
    div1.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    div1.classList.remove("active");
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.div1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: aqua;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  background: magenta;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div div1"></div>
  <div class="div div2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work with Locomotive Scroll!